# Data is saving to firebase database but not under the correct filename

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a folder that can store data on firebase. It created the folder, but it didn't create it with "MCanvas" as the name, it just gave it random alphanumeric values as the name

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("MCanvas");
```

It didn't show any errors though

Comment: how did you add data inside `child("MCanvas")`?

Comment: Please post your code you have tried

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting random alphanumeric values as the name, it means you are using the `push()` method which generates a unique key (a key made up of random alphanumeric values).

To solve this try the following:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("MCanvas");
mDatabaseReference.child("name").setValue("folder1");
```

Thus you will have the following database:

```
MCanvas
     name : folder1
```